# Trying to create a look-up table but one array has an apostrophe in front

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a look-up table between two arrays which I've created from a text file.

One is letters, `LET = '[AS, DF, EG, ET, AS]'`
The other is numbers, `NUM = [1,3,1,0,6]`

I want to be able to retrieve the number corresponding with the pair of letters.

How can I do this?

I think my problem has something to do with the fact that the `LET` array is a string as indicated by the `" ' "`.  Is there any way I can change this and then tuple the two lists?

Comment: You're right. Change LET to be defined like: LET = ['AS','DF','EG','ET','AS']. There's another problem, though: there are two instances of AS, corresponding with two different numbers. Don't know how you want to handle that.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to create the lists from the file?  And can you shows us what the file looks like?

Answer (score 1):

`'[AS, DF, EG, ET, AS]'` is a string. You need to fix your code so it is a list of strings as imm suggests.

Now you can use zip() with the two lists to make a dictionary

```
>>> LET = ['AS','DF','EG','ET','AS']
>>> NUM = [1,3,1,0,6]
>>> dict(zip(LET, NUM))
{'DF': 3, 'ET': 0, 'AS': 6, 'EG': 1}
```

note that there is only one of the values for `'AS'` in the dictionary since you can't have duplicate keys